# add-migrations is disabling nullables in auto generated file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, .net-7.0

I recently updated my project from .net 5 to .net 7 - issue is properly related to this.

When I run [add-migration nameofmychanges] I'm getting a lot of changes without me changing anything.

In the top of the class ContextModelSnapshot.cs there is added a #nullable disable and I see a lot of lines where it wants to change all my entities to nullable:false and default:0.

But also see many of these changes:

From:

```
b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

To:

```
b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));
```

And another example:

From:

```
b.HasOne("EFDataAccessLayer.Entities.User", "CreatedBy")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CreatedById");
```

To:

```
b.HasOne("EFDataAccessLayer.Entities.User", "CreatedBy")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CreatedById")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
```

1. How can I stop the line "#nullable disable" from appearing in the ContextModelSnapshot.cs which is auto generated.
2. The two examples, are they normal to have as changes when moving from .net5 to .net7, or what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop the line "#nullable disable" from appearing in the `ContextModelSnapshot.cs` which is auto generated.

I would argue you should not bother.

> When I run [add-migration nameofmychanges] I'm getting a lot of changes without me changing anything.
> The two examples, are they normal to have as changes when moving from .net5 to .net7, or what is happening?

You should check if the migration itself is empty - if it is then you should be able to freely ignore the snapshot changes. If there are some (and I assume there will be) - you need either disable nullable reference type for your database project (for example with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`), or follow the convention by marking the corresponding properties as via changing them to be NRE (i.e. `string` -> `string?`, also possibly there is a way to disable the convention but I don't remember out of my head)

Read more:

- [Entity Properties - Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions)
- [EF Core Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types)

Comment: I decided to update with all of the migration changes and everything seems the same afterwards. Had some issues but solved this by setting OnDelete to restricted on some entities. I will look at it again soon and try to look at your recommendations even though I did try the <Nullable>enabled</Nullable> with no luck.